# An irreducible, aperiodic and recurrent Markov chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Suppose $X_n,n=0,1,2,...$ is a Markov chain with transition probability $(p_{ij})$. Let $p_{0j}>0,j=0,1,2,...$ and for all $i \geq 1$
$$\sum^{\infty}_{j=0}jp_{ij}\leq i-\frac{1}{10}.$$
I have no idea to prove that $X_n$ is irreducible, aperiodic and recurrent. Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The left hand side is an expectation.  Use the inequality show that for every $i \geq 1$, we have $p_{ij} \neq 0$ for some $j < i$.  From there, it's easy to show that the markov chain is irreducible and recurrent.

We can also show that the period at state zero, namely $\gcd\{n>0 : \mathbb P(X_n = 0\mid X_0 = 0) > 0\}$, is $1$. Because we know that the chain is irreducible, this is enough to deduce that the chain is aperiodic.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newcomer in Markov chain. You mean $E_i(X_n)\leq i-\frac{1}{10}$ ? Then how can I deduce that $p_{ij}$ ≠$0$ for some $j<i$ ?

Comment: I mean that $E(X_{n+1} \mid X_n = i) \leq i - \frac 1{10}$.  Is that what your notation means?

Comment: Yes, I got it. But how can I use $E(X_{n+1}\mid X_n=i)\leq i-\frac{1}{10}$ to deduce that $p_{ij}\neq 0$ for some $j<i$?

Comment: Try to figure that out on your own.  As a hint, try a proof by contradiction: if $p_{ij} = 0$ for all $j<i$, then we must have $E(X_{n+1} \mid X_n = i) \geq i > i - \frac 1{10}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!